# On an equivalence of definitions of a transitive set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The definition I have of a transitive set $A$ is such that $x\in A \Rightarrow x\subseteq A$.

In an exercise, I'm asked to prove that: $$A \mbox{ is transitive} \iff [(B\in C \land C\in A) \Rightarrow B\in A]$$ I have already made the $(\Rightarrow)$ implication the following way:

$$B\in C \land C\in A  \Rightarrow B\in C \land C\subseteq A \Rightarrow B\in A$$

But I don't know how to derive the other implication. I know I must start by taking an $x\in A$ and I must finish with $x\subseteq A$ using $[(B\in C \land C\in A) \Rightarrow B\in A]$ as a hypothesis. **Any hints?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint is that the claim is a tautology. Perhaps reading the definitions out loud will help you. $A$ is transitive means $x\in A$ implies $x\subseteq A$. In words: every element in a set in $A$ is itself in $A$. Now, the condition $B\in C\wedge C\in A \implies B\in A$ can be stated in words as: every element belonging to a set in $A$ is itself in $A$.